# Rounding a double not correct output

Tags: c#

I am trying to round a number and the expected output isn't correct. Here's what I have tried:

```
 var percent = Math.Round(1.13451, 0);
```

That above return's `1`, but I want it to return `1.13` if the 3rd number is less than 5. If it's >= 5 (the third number) I want to get something like `1.135`. I am sure it's something simple I am missing, but not sure.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for this function?  What do you think the second parameter does?  How do you expect the function as currently written knows that you want to round to 2 decimal places, and not 3, or 15, or 1?

Comment: @paddy I've tried specifying the second parameter, but it's not working for my expected output.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_

Comment: You're explicitly asking for it to round your number to 0 decimal places.

Comment: @Cosmos - You should let us know what you've tried.

Comment: @paddy then are you saying I would need a new function to determine this?

Comment: I think you threw everybody off by the way you asked your question, and the disjointed supporting code example.  I have provided an answer that I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are causing confusion because you're using the term "rounding" to describe an operation that is not actually rounding.

I've read your description again, and I can see that you're trying to truncate your values into the highest discrete increment of 0.005 that does not exceed the value.

You can do this as follows:

```
var percent = Math.Floor(200.0 * x) / 200.0;
```

Or, if you want it to be more obvious what's happening, this is essentially the same thing:

```
var increment = 0.005
var percent = Math.Floor(x / increment) * increment;
```

Comment: Both work great, thanks for the explanation and understanding.

Comment: Also I apologize for any confusion, I should have re-worded the question with better details to be honest.

Comment: Paddy - could you please edit the question so answer actually makes sense (there are plenty of existing examples https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+round+nearest+5 so should be easy to do so)

Answer (score 2):

you have to write it with the amount of decimals you want.  `var percent = Math.Round(1.13451, 2);`

---

Updated: I think this is the easiest way to do it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var percent = 1.13551;

    char[] percent1 = percent.ToString().ToCharArray();
    
    if (percent1[4] <= 5)
    {
        percent = Math.Round(percent, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        percent = Math.Round(percent, 2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(percent);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: `1.14` it gives me this if my number is `1.13551`, it should be `1.135`...?

Comment: Then that's _three_ decimal places....  Plus, rounding 1.13551 to 3 places is 1.136

Comment: @paddy `1.136` that's the output I get (using 3 places) if value is `1.13551` and it's wrong. It should be `1.135`. I mentioned in my post about the 3 number after the decimal...

Comment: It is NOT wrong.  This is how rounding works.

Comment: Yeah, as @paddy said from 5 and up it goes up a number.

Comment: @paddy specifically if the 3rd decimal is >=5 I want that third number... So if I have `1.1245` that would only be `1.12`, on the other hand say I have `1.1265`, I should only get back `1.126`. Can this not be done and TBH I've tried different numbers and to no availability. Would I need a special function to handle this?

Comment: You seem to be asking for rounding to 2 and 3 decimal places depending on a condition. And yes, most things can be done, but not always with built-in methods.

Comment: @Cosmos if the thrid number is 5 then it will be rounded up. That is how rounding works.

Comment: @John thanks for the understanding, it seems the method I am using wont work. It seems I'll need to write an extension and or a new method to give me the format I need.

Comment: @BForce what if `percent1[4]` doesn't exists, it will fail. My numbers are different and may not be the same length.

Comment: So, how much decimal numbers do you want to output? You said you want three, if that's the case there is no difference on how many other number you add, we only look at the first 3.

Comment: @BForce it depends, the max would be 3 after the decimal place.

Comment: @Cosmos correct.

Comment: @BForce - Please don't edit answers in a way that invalidates existing comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var percent = Math.Round(1.13451, 2);
```

Inside an `if` statement

Comment: Please explain your reasoning behind why this should be done "inside an `if` statement", and what that would look like.